# MySQLi prepared statement complains that "only variables should be passed by reference"

Tags: mysqli, php

Code:

```
$stmt->bind_param("s", md5($input['user'] . $config['salt']));
```

PHP Error Message:

> Only variables should be passed by reference

I've been working on this project but I am stuck now. I am new to PHP. What to do?

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots of code.  Instead, paste the code itself.  When line numbers matter, simply point out the bad line.

Comment: http://php.net/language.references.pass

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks for using MySQLi prepared statements!  They're a pain, but it's worth it.

[`bind_param`](http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.bind-param) takes values by *reference*.  It does this by looking at the variable you're passing and pointing at the innards directly.

In your call, you're returning the string result of a function call - `md5` in this case.  Because there's no variable involved, there are no innards to point to.  PHP is whining about not being able to pass the data by reference as a result.

You will need to stick the result of the function call into a variable, then pass that variable into the bind instead.

**BIG FAT WARNING!** `md5` is *not* a secure hash any longer, and should *not* be used to store passwords.  When you get the chance, you should update to a better hash format, such as [bcrypt, PBKDF2, scrypt, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/401656/168868).

Comment: Thank you @charles. The error now has gone away, but I am still not about to log into the system, even though my password and username are correct. When i click submit, it suppose to direct me to the members page (line 54). Instead, It displayed the error message in line 60 . $stmt->execute(); $stmt->store_result(); if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) { //set session variable $_SESSION['username'] = $input['user']; header("Location: members.php");//line 54 } else { //username/password incorrect $error['alert'] = "Username or password incorrect!";//line60 –

Comment: MD5 was designed as a Message Digest and was never intended to store passwords.

Answer (score 5):

Every parameter (but the first) of the [`bind_param` method](http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.bind-param) must be a variable and not as in your case, a function return value. Only variables can be [passed by reference](http://php.net/language.references.pass).

With this in mind, you can easily change the code to get rid of the error message:

```
$input['hash'] = md5($input['pass'] . $config['salt']);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $input['user'], $input['hash']);
```

Comment: Thank you @hakre. The error now has gone away, but I am still not about to log into the system, even though my password and username are  correct. When i click submit, it suppose to direct me to  the members page (line 54). Instead, It displayed the error message in line 60 .
 
 
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->store_result();
 
 if ($stmt->num_rows > 0)
 {
 //set session variable
 $_SESSION['username'] = $input['user'];
 
 header("Location: members.php");//line 54
 }
 else
 {
 //username/password incorrect
 $error['alert'] = "Username or password incorrect!";//line60

Comment: If you are sure that username and password are correct, then it's obvious that their processing must contain the problem. See here for some general infos http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php Also please improve your question here and make your actual / follow-up problem clear. You already had some comments yesterday and I did some partial edits on my own, but please continue where I stopped.