# Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: php, mysql

The following is my PHP code.

```php
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    header("Location: /");
}

require 'database.php';

$message = '';

    if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):
        //Enter the new user in the database.
        $sql ="INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES(:email, :password)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':password',password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
        if ($stmt->execute()):
            $message = 'successfully created new user';
        else:
            $message = 'Sorry there must have been an issue creating your an account.';
        endif;
    endif;
```

It shows an error saying that:

> Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\auth\register.php on line 17

On line 17, this following code lies:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':password',password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
```

Any idea what the problem is and what ***Only variables should be passed by reference*** means?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`bind_param` takes values by reference. It does this by looking at the variable you're passing and pointing at the innards directly.

In your call, you're returning the string result of a function call - password_hash in this case. Because there's no variable involved, there are no innards to point to. PHP is whining about not being able to pass the data by reference as a result.

You will need to stick the result of the function call into a variable, then pass that variable into the bind instead.

Try this:

```
$password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$stmt->bindParam(':password',$password );
```

Credit: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794976/mysqli-prepared-statement-complains-that-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-ref)

Comment: It may not be entirely a case of "whining" I found that adding this step also stopped some problems related to quotes in a string variable

Answer (score 5):

```
    $hashedpassword = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password',$hashedpassword );
```

Answer (score -1):

First make

```
$password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

Then this

```
$stmt->bindParam(':password',$password );
```